# PhpStorm File Watcher for SCSS not compiling node_modules

Tags: wordpress, sass, wordpress-theming, phpstorm

I'm working on a custom theme for my local WordPress site. I've set up a `File Watcher` in PhpStorm that compiles my scss files in `myTheme/scss/` to `myTheme/style.css`.

This works as intended, the variables which I've declared in `_variables.scss` are able to be used in `style.css` or any file imported after it.

My problem now is that the `@import '~foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';` is being compiled as `@import '~foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';` instead of the actual css content.

[image: Printscreen of result]

I've tried using `@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';` instead but this compiles the same way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure I follow you... Did you expect `foundation.min.css` to be copied to your resultant `.css` instead of being added as `@import`? Or?

Comment: Yes, I expected `@import '~foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';` to output its  content instead of the @import string.

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

`.css` extension in import statement tells the compiler to generate plain CSS import instead of pulling the contents in; see https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/556#issuecomment-397771726 for reference.
I'd suggest changing your import to 
`@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation'` - this should help.
Note that `~` prefix is a webpack feature SASS compiler is not aware of. So, when using SASS in your file watcher, you have to either change paths to relative or pass `--load-path node_modules/` to compiler

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206351659-PhpStrom-s-SASS-file-watcher-ignores-import-ed-file-in-CSS-generation) solved it for me. Uncheck `Track only root files`, which is defaultly checked.
[image]

Comment: I've had this option turned off from the start.